# how to exclude amd_3dnow instruction set when compiling openssl

Tags: openssl, solaris-10

on our production solaris x86 server we dont have a compiler, so i have to compile on a separate solaris x86. The compilation server has the md_3dnow instruction set, but the production server does not. Is there a way to tell openssl config or make to exclude amd_3dnow instructions of the libssl.so? isainfo -v on the prod/target server tells:

- 64-bit amd64 applications: pclmulqdq aes sse4.2 sse4.1 ssse3 popcnt tscp cx16 mon sse3 pause sse2 sse fxsr mmx cmov amd_sysc cx8 tsc fpu
- 32-bit i386 applications: clmulqdq aes sse4.2 sse4.1 ssse3 popcnt tscp cx16 mon sse3 pause sse2 sse fxsr mmx cmov sep cx8 tsc fpu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `./config`, use `./Configure` to manually configure the source tree (probably specifying either `solaris64-x86_64-gcc` or `solaris-x86-gcc` as the OS/compiler).

Since you appear to have a Core i7 CPU with AES, you could also specify `-march=corei7-avx` (if you have a recent enough gcc) to get a build that is optimised for your production CPU.  It won't run on your build system, though.  Consult [the list of supported `-march` options for gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html) on x86 / x86-64.

Comment: currently I use solaris studio 12 "./Configure solaris-x86-cc threads shared zlib". I also have the latest gcc,, will wive it a try